# I changed the url from the setting then login panel not working

Tags: site-url

i made my whole website on word press my folder name is "pti" and database name also is "pti". at the end i went to the setting by mistake and change the url from "pti" to "NA-239-Pti-Korangi" then whole website went to an error . it redirecting me to NA-239-Pti-Korangi instead of pti

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to fix this:

1. Change your local directory of your root install to "NA-239-Pti-Korangi", or
2. Poke into your database and update `siteurl` in the `<prefix>_options` table

Comment: or there are other ways [to fix the site URL manually](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/#changing-the-site-url) too